# restarting ffmpeg upon stop/disconnection

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'm recording a long audio m3u8 stream with ffmpeg (with -t to limit the time).

the problem is the stream resets its connection quite often.
how do I make ffmpeg restart upon hangs?
I was thinking of running of such a hack:

`timeout <time> while [[ 1 ]]; do ffmpeg -i <mystream> <outfile.mp3>`

but it would override the same file

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as it usually happens, a more careful reading of the man page revealed the solution.

I also learned that now it's better to use avconv over ffmpeg for its better support of hls.

once I marked the stream as an m3u8 one (actually it's called hls)

`ffmpeg hls+http://<stream url> -t <timeout> <output file.mp3>`

happy converting everyone

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to concat mp3. Tell ffmpeg to write to stdout and redirect it to a file.

```
timeout 60 while [[ 1 ]]; do ffmpeg -i mystream - >> outfile.mp3
```

Comment: thanks a lot. that would probably work but I found a simpler solution